# Output OS in Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I'm trying to get the disk config, amongst other information from the guest OS (windows) and I can't seem to work out how to get the information using Azure DevOps, this is required as we would like to Automate the task at the point of migration to see what size disks are added and what spare capacity there is. Also we'll be expanding on this with further WMI queries, but I think once I can run a script against the guest OS I can pull out most of the details I need.

Azure DevOps has Contributor on the subscription

I'm using an inline script:

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName "$(ResourceGroupName)' -Name '$(VMName)' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath ".\_snapshots\drop\CSV\disk.ps1" -Confirm:$false
```

The disk.ps1 script is:

```
$lists = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | ? {$_.VolumeName -ne "Temporary Storage"}

$Report = @()
foreach ($list in $lists) {

$info = "" |   Select-Object DeviceID,"Size (GB)","FreeSpace (GB)","% FreeSpace",VolumeName
$info.DeviceID = $list.DeviceID
$info.'Size (GB)' = [math]::Round($list.size / 1GB)
$info.'FreeSpace (GB)' = [math]::Round($list.FreeSpace / 1GB)
$info.'% FreeSpace' = [math]::Round((($info.'FreeSpace (GB)' * 100) / $info.'Size (GB)'),0)
$info.VolumeName = $list.VolumeName

 $report+=$info 

} 
$report
```

The output I get is:

```
Value     : {Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.InstanceViewStatus, 
           Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.InstanceViewStatus}
Name      : 
StartTime : 
EndTime   : 
Status    : Succeeded
Error     : 
Output    : 
Capacity  : 0
Count     : 0
Item      :
```

What should I get is:

```
Value[0]        : 
  Code          : ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded
  Level         : Info
  DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
  Message       : DeviceID       : C:
  Size (GB)      : 127
 FreeSpace (GB) : 117
 % FreeSpace    : 92
 VolumeName     : Windows
```

I get this when I run the script through PowerShell, same version in both cases.

Can anyone see what I'm missing or where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the inline script as below:

```
$run = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName "$(ResourceGroupName)' -Name '$(VMName)' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath ".\_snapshots\drop\CSV\disk.ps1" -Confirm:$false
Write-Host $run.Value[0]
```

If you want to get the specific message, you could also use:

```
Write-Host $run.Value[0].Message
```

Comment: I've tried that and now just getting "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.InstanceViewStatus"

Comment: @NorrinRad did you get how to fix this issue ? I'm getting the same messgae typoe, but for a bash script.